# Upgraded to test branch by mistake in debian... how can I go back to stable?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, test, debian-installer

I wanted to upgrade my GLIBC to a newer version on my remote server (to which I only have SSH access), so I added the test branch of Debian to my apt sources. I followed this by the mistake of upgrading my whole system to the test branch with both

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now Debian Jessie is out, and I wonder whether I can go to that branch with no problems.

Comment: Are you saying you are on Jessie now? Don't do any more upgrading.Change your source from testing to jessie. Then check and see how many packages are of a version more recent than jessie.

Comment: @FaheemMitha No I'm not on Jessie. I'm on wheezy, but with testing branch enabled in sources.list

Comment: Ok, well you should be aware that testing will change to the next version after jessie shortly, if it has not already done so. So, to prevent further issues, I suggest you rename `testing` to jessie in your `sources.list`. Also, post what you have in your `/etc/apt/preferences` or `/etc/apt/preferences.d`.

Comment: The next release after jessie is stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until a few hours ago `testing` was effectively `jessie`, so you should be able to cross-grade without trouble. Simply replace `testing` with `jessie` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`...

If you switched to `testing` after `testing` was unfrozen, you'll need to downgrade packages; you can use `apt-show-versions` to find packages which are from `testing` rather than from `jessie` (install the package if you don't have it).